# Cx_freeze --- Do all users need python?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I just created an exe with cx_Freeze and proudly handed it over to a co-worker.....and it promptly crashed ("The application was unable to start correctly") I was curious to know if he must have python already installed and ready to go when he runs my exe or if it is something else that I should be worried about. (If that is the case, I will do some more research)

I am using Python 2.7 64 bit, Wxpython, and Cx_Freeze 4.2.7

UPDATE:

So I have found that a download of Python 2.7 DOES indeed fix the problem--but this is not what I really want. I have heard that with the correct options selected in the setup.py script that I can truly  create a stand alone--Does ANYONE know about how I could do this? Filesize is no object.

Comment: And what version of your OS and OS of your mate?

Comment: We are both on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of cx_Freeze is so that the user doesn't need Python installed. But sometimes there might be some DLL dependencies that aren't sorted out automatically by cx_Freeze. For one example, see my recent [question and answer for "ImportError: DLL load failed when importing win32clipboard in application frozen with cx_Freeze"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130605/60075).

But if you're getting the message "The application was unable to start correctly", then that sounds as though the problem is some implicit-linking DLL dependency. Try using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to track down which DLL is missing. Let us know your results.

Comment: Exactly right. Eventually, I found that I was using cx_Freeze incorrectly and that there is a way to do some bundling in there as well to avoid the python dependency.

Comment: I was missing the Gdata library that had not found its way in there.

Comment: cx_freeze needs to be updated. i need it so much for my tkinter program running on windows 7 without python installed

Answer (score 2):

No, he doesn't need to have Python installed - cx_Freeze should copy a Python DLL into the build folder. Make sure that all the files in the build folder are still with the EXE when you run it.

However, it might be necessary for him to install the Microsoft 'Visual C++ redistributable' that Python requires. I don't *think* cx_Freeze can automatically include that, for legal reasons (but I am not a lawyer, and I'm happy to be proved wrong). The details are in the documentation:

http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#microsoft-visual-c-2008-redistributable-package

Or there may be some other problem with the bundling for your application. I don't know what would cause that error message.

Comment: Tried the download--Still getting the same error. Thank you though.