# ImportError: DLL load failed when importing win32clipboard in application frozen with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, cx-freeze

I've got a Python 2.7 program that imports `win32clipboard`. I tried to freeze it with cx_Freeze 4.2.3 on Windows XP SP3 32-bit, to create an installation MSI. I made a `setup.py` according to the cx_Freeze documentation, and used the following command:

```
c:\python27\python.exe setup.py bdist_msi
```

When I run it on another PC that doesn't have Python 2.7 installed, I get an exception on the line that imports `win32clipboard`:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I can see that `win32clipboard.pyd` *is* being included in the build.

What dependency is missing, and how can I ensure it is included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually figured that `win32clipboard.pyd` *is* being included, however, `win32clipboard.pyd` depends on `pywintypes27.dll`, which cx_Freeze is *not* copying from `c:\windows\system32`.

The short-term hack is to manually copy `c:\windows\system32\pywintypes27.dll` into `build\exe.win32-2.7`, then run `setup.py bdist_msi` again.

An improved hack is to use the following in the setup.py:

```
import os
import sys
import win32api
...
pywintypes_dll = 'pywintypes{0}{1}.dll'.format(*sys.version_info[0:2])      # e.g. pywintypes27.dll
build_exe_options = {..., "include_files": [ (os.path.join(win32api.GetSystemDirectory(), pywintypes_dll), pywintypes_dll)]}
...
setup(  ...,
        options = { 'build_exe': build_exe_options, 
                    ...,
                  },
        ...)
```

(It would be preferable for cx_Freeze to be improved to automatically detect the `pywintype27.dll` dependency, but I guess that's always a work-in-progress.)

Answer (score 2):

cx_Freeze uses a hooking mechanism to handle this sort of situation.  The hooks are stored in the module `cx_Freeze.hooks`.  Each hook is named after the action being investigated, load or missing, and the module name.  The module itself provides lots of examples.

Here is how you'd handle the win32clipboard module:

```
from cx_Freeze import hooks
def load_win32clipboard(finder, module):
    finder.IncludeModule("pywintypes")

hooks.load_win32clipboard = load_win32clipboard
...
```

Now when cx_Freeze encounters win32clipboard, it will also include pywintypes.  cx_Freeze already has a pywintypes hook that will copy the appropriate file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try it some time. That last line looks like a strange API—in effect, monkey-patching the `cx_Freeze.hooks` module.