# ImportError: DLL load failed: when importing

Tags: python, dll, import, module

I have installed `pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.4` (it was succesfull and I restart my computer after) to be able to `import win32clipboard`

But now I am getting this error: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`.

On this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130605/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-win32clipboard-in-application-frozen), it is adviced to copy `c:\windows\system32\pywintypes27.dll` into `build\exe.win32-2.7`, then run `setup.py bdist_msi` again. But I don't have this `DLL`. Also I don't use `cx_Freeze`.

Comment: it seems to be related to a version mismatch between module & python version (eg. a module for 32 running in a python for 64). Some source says we could use a 32 version (python and module) in a windows 64 (the opposite won't work)